# passing data through routerLink and call function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, routerlink, angular-routerlink

I am trying to pass data through the routerLink and call `function()`. But it not working. This is my example code and [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-button-routerlink-fvbm5s) demo.

**First Component(HTML)**

```
<span [routerLink]="/upcoming" [state]="{ data: {value}}">{{name}}</span>
```

**Second Component(ts)**

```
updateCategory(event) {console.log(event)}
```

Comment: Hi @Pravu, your question is insufficient in detail. Please create a simple example on stackblitz or describe your problem for more context.

Comment: Hi @HanChe.. ., I've provide stackblitz

Comment: Maybe you can use onChanges and add a control variable with decorator @Input. You can use a service with the location and inject in the child and get the value.

Comment: Do you want to pass data to another component? In that case it would be cleaner to use a service instead of trying to send data with the route. Please specify your question with what the intention of this is.

Comment: Yup.. I want to open another component and passing data to call function that component when load.. But I don't have any idea how to make it working

Comment: Please read through https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction and see if it helps you.

Comment: You want to read page 1 router state from page1component?

Comment: from `app.component.html` to page1 compnent and call function

Comment: I've follow what Mike S and ALourenço advice..and it working now... Thank you so much both of you

Answer (score 0):

In order to call a function in the new routed component, you can use angular's component lifecycle hooks. The data passed via the `State` Input can be accessed by `history.state` in the new component.

```
export class Page1Component implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
     const data = history.state.data
     this.updateCategory(data)
  }

  updateCategory(event) {
    console.log(event)
  }

}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-button-routerlink-dhvxw8

Comment: You can bind to data whatever your want [state]="{data:categories}"
Unless you specify in detail what it is you want to accomplish, nobody can help you :)

Comment: Never mind.. I've follow what ALourenço and Mike S. teach... and it working